# Change Wordpress User Roles with access to Private Pages

Tags: wordpress, function, private, user-roles

I have a user role called Student and would like to allow them access to Private pages (currently only admin and editor roles can do this). I would like to create a function to do so. I found a post that said to add this to the functions.php in my child theme:

```
// Allow Students to see Private posts and pages  
$subRole = get_role( 'Student' );   
$subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );  
$subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a way to change the ability to access private pages?

Also above it says 'read_private_pages' I want to be sure that they can submit the form on that page as well (not just read the page).

Answer (score 2):

Do you can use plugins? If yes, try the plugin [Capability Manager Enhanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/).

This plugin is a way to manage WordPress role definitions.
More easy that edit direct in the code.

Comment: Thanks, that works but I would rather not have an entire plugin to do this if I can just add some code to the functions.php. It will work for now but if anyone else has some code that will do the same I'd love to use it!

Comment: @MattM I am going to test some codes. But, test your code lowercase, like that: `get_role( 'student' );` I put the S of Student lower.

Comment: Thanks DR.Somar, I had originally tried it with a lowercase and then changed it to uppercase.